# Intersection of arrays in LINQ to CosmosDB

Tags: linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying find all items in my database that have at least one value in an array that matches any value in an array that I have in my code (the intersection of the two arrays should not be empty).

Basically, I'm trying to achieve this :

```
public List<Book> ListBooks(string partitionKey, List<string> categories)
{
    return _client.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(GetCollectionUri(), new FeedOptions
    {
        PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey)
    })
    .Where(b => b.Categories.Any(c => categories.Contains(c))
    .ToList();
}
```

With the Book class looking like this :

```
public class Book
{
    public string id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string AuthorName {get;set;}
    public List<string> Categories {get;set;}
}
```

However the SDK throws an exception saying that Method 'Any' is not supported when executing this code.
This doesn't work either :

```
return _client.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(GetCollectionUri(), new FeedOptions
{
    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey)
})
.Where(b => categories.Any(c => b.Categories.Contains(c))
.ToList();
```

The following code works because there's only one category to find :

```
public List<Book> ListBooksAsync(string category)
{
    return _client.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(GetCollectionUri())
    .Where(b => b.Categories.Contains(category))
    .ToList();
}
```

In plain SQL, I can queue multiple `ARRAY_CONTAINS` with several `OR` the query executes correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM root 
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["Categories"], 'Humor')
   OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["Categories"], 'Fantasy')
   OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["Categories"], 'Legend')
```

I'm trying to find the best way to achieve this with LINQ, but I'm not even sure it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this situation I've used a helper method to combine expressions in a way that evaluates to SQL like in your final example. The helper method 'MakeOrExpression' below lets you pass a number of predicates (in your case the individual checks for b.Categories.Contains(category)) and produces a single expression you can put in the argument to .Where(expression) on your document query.

```
class Program
{
    private class Book
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public List<string> Categories { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var comparison = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };

        var target = new Book[] {
            new Book { id = "book1", Categories = new List<string> { "b", "z" } },
            new Book { id = "book2", Categories = new List<string> { "s", "t" } },
            new Book { id = "book3", Categories = new List<string> { "z", "a" } } };

        var results = target.AsQueryable()
            .Where(MakeOrExpression(comparison.Select(x => (Expression<Func<Book, bool>>)(y => y.Categories.Contains(x))).ToArray()));

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            // Should be book1 and book3
            Console.WriteLine(result.id);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T,bool>> MakeOrExpression<T>(params Expression<Func<T,bool>>[] inputExpressions)
    {
        var combinedExpression = inputExpressions.Skip(1).Aggregate(
            inputExpressions[0].Body, 
            (agg, x) => Expression.OrElse(agg, x.Body));

        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        var replaceParameterVisitor = new ReplaceParameterVisitor(parameterExpression, 
            Enumerable.SelectMany(inputExpressions, ((Expression<Func<T, bool>> x) => x.Parameters)));

        var mergedExpression = replaceParameterVisitor.Visit(combinedExpression);

        var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(mergedExpression, parameterExpression);
        return result;
    }

    private class ReplaceParameterVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<ParameterExpression> targetParameterExpressions;
        private readonly ParameterExpression parameterExpression;

        public ReplaceParameterVisitor(ParameterExpression parameterExpressionParam, IEnumerable<ParameterExpression> targetParameterExpressionsParam)
        {
            this.parameterExpression = parameterExpressionParam;
            this.targetParameterExpressions = targetParameterExpressionsParam;
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
            => targetParameterExpressions.Contains(node) ? this.parameterExpression : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```